# Generating function polynomial recurrence relation e.g. $a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n+1$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Suppose $(a_n)_n$ satisfies for example the following recurrence relation:
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n^2+a_n+1,
$$
is the notion of generating function etc. to analyse the sequence $(a_n)_n$ still applicable on this type of problem? Or does this whole concept disappear on this type of recurrence relation because of $\sum_n a_n^2 x^n$?

Comment: This kind of sequence is hard to deal with (except computationally). [oeis](https://oeis.org) A002065 gives $a_n=\lfloor c^{2^n}\rfloor$ with $c=1.385089248\dots$.

Comment: OEIS gives https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C26%2C677%2C458330 as the number of binary trees of height less than or equal to $n$.